# SELECT WHERE id = 1 but returned id = 11?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables; let's just call them foo_table and bar_table.
So, foo_table's id is a foreign key for bar_table.
And in bar_table there is foo_table's id = 11

BUT, when I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM bar_table AS b 
  INNER JOIN foo_table AS f ON b.foo_id = f.foo_id 
   WHERE b.foo_id = 1
```

It should return NULL because there isn't any data in bar_table with foo_id = 1 but it returns data with foo_id = 11

Can anybody fix it?
**UPDATE**
Sorry I didn't write my table...

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d0821/1)

Comment: Can you actually provide a table with real data that you're using for this query and what you're getting for a result?

Comment: What is the data type of the `foo_id` column in both tables? That detail is relevant. If you want help here, provide *real, specific information* instead of *let's say something is...* nonsense.

Comment: Provide SQL Fiddle with sample data.

Comment: @SirajulHaq: No. The poster should provide the DDL here, in the question itself, and not off-site. The statements to CREATE TABLE and the DML to INSERT some sample data as text in this question on this site are what is needed. We shouldn't have to leave this site to see information that is extremely relevant to the question.

Comment: As long as some more information is provided as to the structure, the data he's actually using and what he gets for a return then that's all most people care about.

Comment: [Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/236f65/1) with the tables and SQL statement. I was not able to reproduce the issue. I suspect that the actual data (or field types) in your database is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always group boolean operations. This will make certain that they are interpreted in the manner you desire.

```
WHERE k.id_pegawai = '1'
  AND (k.status_keluarga = 'suami' OR k.status_keluarga = 'istri')
```